# Different behavior between g++ and clang++ in nested classes

Tags: c++, gcc, c++17, clang++

I noticed a different behavior between `gcc` 9.2.0 and `clang++` 9.0.1. My code is as follows

```
//header.hh
     ...
template <typename T>
class Outer {
     ...
  public:
     template <typename S>
     class Inner;
     ... 
};

template <typename T>
template <typename S>
class Inner {
     ...
      Inner& func();
     ...
};
```

then, since the function `func()` is implemented in another file

```
//implementation.cc
template <typename T>
template <typename S>
Outer<T>::Inner<S>& Outer<T>::Inner<S>::func() {
    ...
};
```

Now, if I use `g++` the compilation is OK. If I use `clang++` I get

```
src/implementation.cc:6:1: error: missing 'typename' prior to dependent type template name 'Outer<T>::Inner'
Outer<T>::Inner<S>& Outer<T>::Inner<S>::func() {
^
1 error generated.
```

However if I follow its suggestion and use

```
typename Outer<T>::Inner<S>& Outer<T>::Inner<S>::func()
```

I got another error:

```
src/implementation.cc:6:21: error: use 'template' keyword to treat 'Inner' as
a dependent template name typename Outer<T>::Inner<S>& Outer<T>
::Inner<S>::func() {
```

And now its suggestion seems very weird.

## QUESTIONS

1. Why the two compiler are behaving differently?
2. What is the correct syntax to use?

Comment: You have a bigger problem to worry about. Even after you square the compilation error, despite the limited information given your question it seems very likely that your program will fail to link, by either compiler, because templates can only be implemented in header files. Your attempt to define the template in something called "implementation.cc" is doomed to an utter and complete failure. C++ simply does not work this way.

Comment: Could you please update your examples, they are inconsistent with error messages (e.g. Inner-Outer order, Iterator class).

Comment: That too, you need to [edit] your question to contain only one code snippet that demonstrates the compilation error you're asking about.

Comment: I edited the question. However I'm very sorry for my ignorance. I simply did not know that one cannot separate definition of a template from the declaration.

Comment: Your question still is short of a [mre]. Can you cut/paste what you have in your question, and reproduce your compilation error? Obviously not, and until it is, it's not a [mre] by definition. The best way to get this kind of help is to make it as easy as possible for everyone else to reproduce your error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be the following:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename S>
typename Outer<T>::template Inner<S> &Outer<T>::Inner<S>::func() {
    ...
}
```

You can find the full explanation for this syntax in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords) question.

However, a simpler and also valid syntax would be this:

```
template <typename T>
template <typename S>
auto Outer<T>::Inner<S>::func() -> Inner& {
    ...
}
```

By using the trailing return type syntax in the example above you can take advantage of the fact that the name resolution scope is within `Outer<T>::Inner<S>` at that point so you can use the [injected class name](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/injected-class-name) of the `Inner`.